# A graph whose automorphism group is the alternating group

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, automorphism-group

I'm looking for an example of a graph whose automorphism group is the alternating group on 4 symbols, A_4. If there is a construction that generalizes to an arbitrary alternating group, then I would love to know it.

Answer (score 4):

$A_4$ is the group of symmetries of a regular tetrahedron that preserve orientation. So something like this should work:

[image: a tetrahedral graph with corner networks that preserve orientation]

This construction can be generalized recursively to larger alternating groups -- for example, for $A_5$ take the complete graph $K_5$ and replace each of the vertices with a copy of the above graph, suitably oriented.